# Explantion for CSRSS.EXE using the GPU

Tags: windows-7, windows, gpu, aero

This is a follow up question to [conhost.exe and csrss.exe questions](https://superuser.com/questions/790309/conhost-exe-and-csrss-exe-questions)

I am currently on a Windows 7 x64 machine, using a relatively high end GPU (GTX 970 4 GB). Windows Aero is enabled. I am using Process Explorer to examine this case.

I have two `csrss.exe` processes running, both as SYSTEM, one under session 0 and one under session 1. I have `csrss.exe` files, both in the correct directories. Using Process Explorer, I can see my GPU is being used only by `csrss.exe`.  The session 1 `csrss.exe` is using it.  Closer examination of the process’s threads reveals these `.dll` files:

```
Cdd.dll
Winsrv.dll
Csrsrv.dll
```

Cdd.dll – the canonical display driver is particularly important here, as described below in some helpful info below a kind user was able to provide for me.

> Under DWM, GDI calls are redirected to use the Canonical Display Driver (cdd.dll), a software renderer.

So perhaps it's something in `csrss.exe` actually redirecting calls to `cdd.dll`. Confirmed further by going back to the first Wikipedia article:
instead of issuing a system call, the Win32 libraries (kernel32.dll, user32.dll, gdi32.dll) send an inter-process call to the CSRSS process which does most of the actual work without compromising the kernel.
So application calls to `gdi32.dll` (which would be anything that renders any Windows GUI component like buttons, scrollbars, text, etc.) end up making their way to `csrss.exe` via IPC, which `csrss.exe` redirects to `cdd.dll`.

So `dwm.exe`, which I would have presumed would have been using the GPU, is instead someway showing through `csrss.exe`.

So that at least explains the story partly. When idle at the desktop, GPU usage is > 0.01%. However, if I interact with certain UI elements of a program, for example hovering over the GPU graphs to bring up stock-like windows UI, or hovering over parts of Steams UI (Steamworks is a video game drm client) the GPU usage for `csrss.exe` rises, maybe a few percent, and depending on what is going on, such as rapidly hovering over Process Explorer graphs, it can go to 15-20%.

I selected the `csrss.exe` process in question and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. I found threads related to `procexp64.exe`, `steamwebhelper.exe` (displays web API for `steam.exe`, which is also under this `csrss.exe`), `explorer.exe`, `dwm.exe`, and anything that seemed that would create windows/stock UI elements.

I tried Safe Mode and creating a new standard user account, but the same activity occurs.

My question is, is this activity normal? Csrss.exe seems to increase its cycle delta when moving the mouse, and when I hover over auch ui. Is the reason hovering over certain aero elements, or programs like steam that may use certain windows elements causing GPU usage to rise under `csrss.exe` because that is the process calling `cdd.dll`? As I said, on idle GPU usage is negligible, which I guess confirms no malicious activity. I suffer no performance issues running high end games with Aero enabled, but I’m wondering if this is normal activity for a high end machine.

Should `csrss.exe` be using the GPU like this when calling on things 
like `cdd.dll` and `winsrv.dll`?

Specs:

- I5 3570k
- GTX 970 4 GB
- 8 GB RAM
- Windows 7, 64-bit

Comment: You seem to be saying that you have two ```csrss.exe``` files — can you elaborate on that?

Comment: `csrss.exe` is involved in rendering/handling the mouse pointer: https://superuser.com/questions/555560/why-is-csrss-exe-called-every-time-i-move-the-mouse

Comment: Are you certain aero glass is on..

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same issue. I was going to terminate `csrss.exe`, but then noticed one thing in Task Manager. The Video Encoder part of the GPU was in use.

So the problem was that my AMD Radeon Crimson [ReLive](https://gaming.radeon.com/en/radeonsoftware/adrenalin/relive/) was doing this thing called 'Instant Replay' in which the gameplay of last few minutes is continuously captured.
Even though I had disabled 'Record Desktop' in settings, it was still recording. So this was just a **bug** which was using GPU.

TL;DR:
Disable Instant Replay. How to disable it? It depends on what recording/streaming software does your PC has. Just Google it.

**Note**:
If disabling Instant Replay does not solve the issue, or it is already OFF or you don't have streaming software, your PC might be infected by a virus or something.